# Debug the CPython opcode stack

Tags: python, ctypes, bytecode, cpython, pdb

CPython 3.7 introduced the ability to step through individual opcodes in a debugger. However, I can't figure out how to read variables out of the bytecode stack.

For example, when debugging

```py
def f(a, b, c):
    return a * b + c

f(2, 3, 4)
```

I want to find out that the inputs of the addition are 6 and 4. Note how 6 never touches `locals()`.

So far I could only come up with the opcode information, but I don't know how to get the opcode inputs:

```py
import dis
import sys


def tracefunc(frame, event, arg):
    frame.f_trace_opcodes = True
    print(event, frame.f_lineno, frame.f_lasti, frame, arg)
    if event == "call":
        dis.dis(frame.f_code)
    elif event == "opcode":
        instr = next(
            i for i in iter(dis.Bytecode(frame.f_code))
            if i.offset == frame.f_lasti
        )
        print(instr)
    print("-----------")
    return tracefunc


def f(a, b, c):
    return a * b + c


sys.settrace(tracefunc)
f(2, 3, 4)
```

Output:

```
call 19 -1 <frame at 0x7f97df618648, file 'test_trace.py', line 19, code f> None
 20           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 RETURN_VALUE
-----------
line 20 0 <frame at 0x7f97df618648, file 'test_trace.py', line 20, code f> None
-----------
opcode 20 0 <frame at 0x7f97df618648, file 'test_trace.py', line 20, code f> None
Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=0, argval='a', argrepr='a', offset=0, starts_line=20, is_jump_target=False)
-----------
opcode 20 2 <frame at 0x7f97df618648, file 'test_trace.py', line 20, code f> None
Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=1, argval='b', argrepr='b', offset=2, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
-----------
opcode 20 4 <frame at 0x7f97df618648, file 'test_trace.py', line 20, code f> None
Instruction(opname='BINARY_MULTIPLY', opcode=20, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=4, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
-----------
opcode 20 6 <frame at 0x7f97df618648, file 'test_trace.py', line 20, code f> None
Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=2, argval='c', argrepr='c', offset=6, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
-----------
opcode 20 8 <frame at 0x7f97df618648, file 'test_trace.py', line 20, code f> None
Instruction(opname='BINARY_ADD', opcode=23, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=8, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
-----------
opcode 20 10 <frame at 0x7f97df618648, file 'test_trace.py', line 20, code f> None
Instruction(opname='RETURN_VALUE', opcode=83, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=10, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
-----------
return 20 10 <frame at 0x7f97df618648, file 'test_trace.py', line 20, code f> 10
-----------
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TLDR

You can inspect CPython's inter-opcode state using a C-extension, gdb, or using dirty tricks (examples below).

## Background

CPython's bytecode is run by a [stack machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine). That means that all state between opcodes is kept in a stack of `PyObject*`s.

Let's take a quick look at CPython's [frame object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/frameobject.h#L16):

```c
typedef struct _frame {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    struct _frame *f_back;      /* previous frame, or NULL */
    PyCodeObject *f_code;       /* code segment */
    ... // More fields
    PyObject **f_stacktop;
    ... // More fields
} PyFrameObject;
```

See the `PyObject **f_stacktop` right near the end? This is a pointer to the top of this stack. Most (if not all?) CPython's opcodes use that stack to get parameters and store results.

For example, let's take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L1539) for `BINARY_ADD` (addition with two operands):

```c
case TARGET(BINARY_ADD): {
    PyObject *right = POP();
    PyObject *left = TOP();
    ... // sum = right + left
    SET_TOP(sum);
    ...
}
```

It pops two values from the stack, add them up and puts the result back in the stack.

## Inspecting the stack

#### Down to C level - C extension or GDB

As we saw above, CPython's frame objects are native - `PyFrameObject` is a struct, and `frameobject.c` defines the pythonic interface allowing to read (and sometimes write) some of its members.

Specifically, the member `f_stacktop` is not exposed in python, so to access this member and read the stack you'll have to write some code in C or use GDB.

Specifically, if you're writing a debugging-utils library, I'd recommend writing a C extension, which will allow you to write some basic primitives in C (like getting the current stack as a list of python objects), and the rest of the logic in python.

If it's a one time thing, you could probably try [playing around with GDB](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) and inspect the stack.

#### When you don't have a compiler - using pure python

The plan: find the address of the stack and read the numbers stored in it from memory - in python!

First, we need to be able to find the offset of `f_stacktop` in the frame object.
I installed a debugging version of python (on my ubuntu it's `apt install python3.7-dbg`). This package includes a python binary that contains debugging symbols (some information about the program made to help debuggers).

`dwarfdump` is a utility that can read and display debugging symbols (DWARF is a common debugging-info format used mostly in ELF binaries).
Running `dwarfdump -S any=f_stacktop -Wc /usr/bin/python3.7-dbg` provides us with the following output:

```
DW_TAG_member
    DW_AT_name                  f_stacktop
    DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000034 ./build-debug/../Include/frameobject.h
    DW_AT_decl_line             0x0000001c
    DW_AT_decl_column           0x00000010
    DW_AT_type                  <0x00001969>
    DW_AT_data_member_location  88
```

`DW_AT_data_member_location` sounds like the offset of `f_stacktop`!

Now let's write some code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.7-dbg
from ctypes import sizeof, POINTER, py_object
# opname is a list of opcode names, where the indexes are the opcode numbers
from opcode import opname
import sys 

# The offset we found using dwarfdump
F_STACKTOP = 88

def get_stack(frame):
    # Getting the address of the stack by adding
    # the address of the frame and the offset of the member
    f_stacktop_addr = id(frame) + F_STACKTOP
    # Initializing a PyObject** directly from memory using ctypes
    return POINTER(py_object).from_address(f_stacktop_addr)

def tracefunc(frame, event, arg):
    frame.f_trace_opcodes = True
    if event == 'opcode':
        # frame.f_code.co_code is the raw bytecode
        opcode = frame.f_code.co_code[frame.f_lasti]
        if opname[opcode] == 'BINARY_ADD':
            stack = get_stack(frame)
            # According to the implementation of BINARY_ADD,
            # the last two items in the stack should be the addition operands
            print(f'{stack[-2]} + {stack[-1]}')
    return tracefunc

def f(a, b, c): 
    return a * b + c 

sys.settrace(tracefunc)
f(2, 3, 4)
```

**The ouput**: `6 + 4`! Great success! (said with satisfied Borat voice)

This code is not portable yet, because `F_STACKTOP` will vary between python binaries. To fix that you could use [`ctypes.Structure`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure) to create a frame object structure and easily get the value of the `f_stacktop` member in a more portable fashion.

Note that doing that will hopefully make your code platform-independent, but it will not make it python-implementation-independent. Code like that might only work with the CPython version you wrote it with originally. This is because to create a `ctypes.Structure` subclass, you will have to rely on CPython's implementation of frame objects (or more specifically, on `PyFrameObject`'s members' types and order).

Comment: I wrote a pure-python version that doesn't rely on a debugger: https://gist.github.com/crusaderky/cf0575cfeeee8faa1bb1b3480bc4a87a

Comment: `f_stacktop` is usually `NULL` - the actual stack top is maintained in a `stack_pointer` local variable. You happen to be examining it during one of the few cases where it's non-NULL - `f_stacktop` is restored while executing a trace function for a `'line'` or `'opcode'` event. (I didn't notice it was restored during those trace calls, so I need to go update one of my old answers that didn't account for that.)

Comment: I'm curious about why the member f_stacktop is not exposed in python, and I want to issue this feature request to the python development team. Where should I go?